# How can i get the label of a text field of existing fillable PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am having an fillable pdf file. I want to know the label name of the input variables.

Answer (score 1):

Fields in PDF don't have visible labels like HTML. However, you can get the tooltip using code similar to below. You'll replace the field name with your own.

```
var tooltip = this.getField("myField").userName
```

"userName" does not refer to the user, it refers to the name of the field that's presented to the user.

Comment: The document which i have to use dose not contain the floating text.